# Unable to reset AD User password using python

Tags: python-3.x, active-directory, ldap3

I am working on  project which requires me to reset AD User password. But I have not found useful resources so far in the web.

I am using ldap3 to reset AD User password but it's not working.
I have visited these links to get some idea to implement the code
1. [Update Active Directory Password using ldap python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603236/update-active-directory-password-using-ldap-python)
2.[Python 3.5, ldap3 and modify_password()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816278/python-3-5-ldap3-and-modify-password)
3.https://serverfault.com/questions/937330/update-ad-password-from-python-ldap-code-insuff-access-rights/937361
4. https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/welcome.html

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, NTLM, ALL
server = Server('mydomain.com',use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user='user1', password='oldpassword', authentication=NTLM, auto_bind=True)
print(conn)

pwd = 'newpassword'
enc_pwd = '"{}"'.format(newpassword).encode('utf-16-le')
conn.modify('cn=user1, ou=ou_name, dc=mydomain, dc=com', {'unicodePwd': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, [enc_pwd])]})
print(conn.result)
```

> Error: raise LDAPSocketOpenError('unable to open socket',
>   exception_history) ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: ('unable
>   to open socket', [(LDAPSocketOpenError('socket ssl wrapping error:
>   [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host'),

Comment: The error message clearly states that it is not able to create a socket connection with AD server using SSL! Can you check if your AD is allowing SSL connection, or otherwise, use false in the SSL parameter (not recommended though). Does your system from which you're using the code has AD server certificate trusted (root CA certificate in system's Trusted Certification Authorities)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a network level error, in my case I was using AWS Managed AD and out of the box it does not support TLS and needed to [spin up a CA](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-enable-ldaps-for-your-aws-microsoft-ad-directory/) to enable TLS over LDAP.

Basically LDAP is there a connection is established but when trying to lift the connection to TLS it fails because TLS was not supported on my LDAP server at the time.